# Storing temporary user files in ASP.NET in medium trust

Tags: asp.net, file-io, medium-trust

I have a scenario where users of my ASP.NET web application submit testimonials consisting of text info and images. The submit process has the following steps:

- First the user inputs the content and chooses a path to an image
- When he clicks preview, the info is once again shown so that he can confirm
- Once confirmed the info is persisted in the database

The problem with this is that I don't want to store uploaded images in the DB before the user actually confirms. Instead I store them as temporary files and put them in DB only after final confirmation.

Since I also want my application to run in medium trust, I have write permissions only to the application directory and nowhere outside. I even want to limit write permissions for the ASPNET / NETWORK SERVICE user to the ~/App_Data folder. The problem with my scenario is that once a temporary file is created in this folder, the application pool is recycled and I don't want that on every testimonial submit.

How do you advise I keep these temp files instead? The pool is not restarted if I update a file - only on create or rename. But I don't think I can store whole images in a single file for all users. What do you think?

**UPDATE**: I should note that I'm using a third party control for upload. It gives me programmatic access to the binary stream of the file contents after upload, but I cannot keep this after a second postback (the first step and postback actually does the upload).

Comment: The app pool should NOT recycle in that scenario. Perhaps a wrong entry in the web.config?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend [IsolatedStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy(VS.80).aspx). It's a kind of virtual folder.

Here is an excerpt from [an example on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/IsolatedStorage.aspx):

```
IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = 
  new IsolatedStorageFileStream(ISOLATED_FILE_NAME, 
  FileMode.Create, isoStore);

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter( stream );
writer.WriteLine( "This is my first line in the isolated storage file." );
writer.WriteLine( "This is second line." );
writer.Close();
```

**UPDATE**: To clean up your file just do this:

```
string fileName = "isolatestorage.txt";

IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(
    IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, null, null);

string[] files = storage.GetFileNames(fileName);
foreach(string file in files) {
    if(file == fileName) {
        storage.DeleteFile(file);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of this. The question is, how do I empty it? It's not a temp folder after all - rather it's used for long-term persistence.

Comment: You could run a cron job to check and empty it.

Comment: @Seb - I know how to do it in code - I just need this done periodically and automatically.

@Chakrit - kind of an overkill. I can't believe no one else had such an issue.

Comment: IsolatedStorage probably isn't bad, but is also not really necessary.  It uses the Windows username for isolation, which isn't that applicable here, right?

Comment: @ScottStafford I'm not sure. Thought it used the Windows-account that is running the app, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can still use the normal [Path.GetTempFilename](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx)() method to get a temporary file  in ASP.NET scenarios.

It should give you a temp file path that is writable by NETWORK_SERVICE but also lives in one of the actual Windows' temp folders, not your application folder.

If your host configured his server correctly, that should works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The default web_mediumtrust.config file that Microsoft ships is notoriously impractical.

Here is a snippet from the default web_mediumtrust.config file.  By default, you cannot use System.IO to discover or write to the temp folder.

```
                        <IPermission
                                class="FileIOPermission"
                                version="1"
                                Read="$AppDir$"
                                Write="$AppDir$"
                                Append="$AppDir$"
                                PathDiscovery="$AppDir$"
                        />
```

Although I haven't experirement with Isolated Storage as mentioned by @Seb, it seems to be permitted by the default config file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a reply to Leppie who commented on my question (to avoid the char limit)

From: http://blogs.msdn.com/johan/archive/2007/05/16/common-reasons-why-your-application-pool-may-unexpectedly-recycle.aspx

> ...sometimes your application pool inexplicably recycles for no obvious reason. This is usually a configuration issue or due to the fact that you're performing file system operations in the application directory.

Are you sure it's not supposed to recycle?

Comment: Normally, only changes in the bin and App_Code directories will cause an app-pool recycle.