# IIS Worker process recycles soonner than the regular time interval set (Both 6.0 and 7.0)

Tags: iis

We've configured our application pool to recycle at a regular time interval of 180 minutes. But the worker processes are getting recycled every 60 minutes.

Is this a known issue, or do we need to configure something else?

Thanks

Comment: I think this question can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302110/what-causes-an-application-pool-in-iis-to-recycle

Answer (score 4):

As stated in [What causes an application pool in IIS to recycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302110/what-causes-an-application-pool-in-iis-to-recycle):

You might want to turn on full AppPool Recycle Event logs:

```
cscript adsutil.vbs Set w3svc/AppPools/DefaultAppPool/LogEventOnRecycle 255
```

You also might want to take a look at this Scott Guthrie blog article: [http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/14/433194.aspx][1] that shows how to write code in Global.ASAX to log the actual cause of an Application.End event.