# Session Expire if i'm not in idle asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2005

I'm getting a problem with session. When I'm not idle and still using webpage the session expires.

Answer (score 0):

If you havent set, the default session timeout is 20 mts. Also it will increment by its own if you are referring or using the session variables.

Are you sure that you are the using session variables during your non-idle time?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using InProc session state it could be that the application domain is being recycled.  This could be due to any number of things, see this question:

[What causes an application pool in IIS to recycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302110/what-causes-an-application-pool-in-iis-to-recycle)