# Asp.net website Publishing

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, web, publishing

if i have a separate dll for each page on my server and that is working fine. if I make some changes in code behind file of a particular page say, xyz.aspx page.
then I have to upload the dll of that particular page. and that refreshes the whole web application and all sessions and other values got disturbed in the application.
Is there any way that uploading the xyz.dll (of page xyz.apsx) on refreshes the xyz.aspx and didn't disturb the whole web application.

Comment: My understaning is that when you drop the dll into the bin directory it will cause the App Domain to be reloaded so that the new dll is picked up. I don't know of a way to get around this. If all of your session was moved out into a State Server you would not loose your session, but you seems to be using in Proc session. For the new DLL to be used the old DLL has to be removed from the App Domain (i.e in memory), and the only way (that I know of in 2.0 at least) is to get rid of the app domain. Thus your loosing session etc.

Answer (score 0):

By default, dropping new assemblies into the vdir is going to cause a recycle to occur.

This question...

[What causes an application pool in IIS to recycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302110/what-causes-an-application-pool-in-iis-to-recycle)

... talks about what causes an app pool recycle. This MSDN article...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/08/02/asp-net-case-study-lost-session-variables-and-appdomain-recycles.aspx

... has an excellent write up about the subject.

As you can see, this refresh is by design.