# erratic behavior of Preload()

Tags: c#, azure, iis-8, application-pool, preload

I have a WCF application hosted in Windows Azure.  It has IIS v8.0

I have used `IProcessHostPreloadClient's` `Preload()` method for application warmup

Now, I have two issues here:

1) whenever my application pool recycles, the `Preload()` function is called  twice. I have some static variables being initialized in the `preload()` method which will persist in my worker process `(w3wp.exe)`.

What I have seen is interesting:

My current worker process `ID` is (`w3wp.exe 1234`,say)

when recycled, `preload` is called twice:

1st Time: in w3wp.exe which has Process `ID`: `5678`,say (a new worker process)

2nd Time: in w3wp.exe which has Process `ID: 1234` (same as the exiting one)

Now, I have configured my app pool so that only one instance of w3wp.exe will be present. Hence after recycle happens, the w3wp.exe that exists is that of process id: 5678.

My question is, why a dying w3wp.exe with process ID: 1234 has executed preload

There is a 3ms gap between both.

**EDIT**
I just learned that what exactly happens is that due to app-pool recycle, an old w3wp.exe terminates and a new w3wp.exe is started.
What causes preload to be called twice is:

1) new process of w3wp.exe - causes preload() to be called on the new process (Process ID: 5678 in our example)

2) the old process of w3wp.exe (Process ID: 1234) : Its app-domain is restarted before it is killed. Hence, when app domain is restarted, preload() is called

**Now, my question is why a dying w3wp.exe's app-domain got restarted. It was about to die anyways in next 3ms (as mentioned above)**

2) I have started the service and I was doing some testing. In between, for sometime, worker process was not serving any requests. But my w3wp.exe has a thread which runs continuously.

What we observer after some time was that, the existing instance of `w3wp.exe` (process id 1234,say) ended abruptly and preload() was called in the same process (`w3wp.exe` with process id 1234)

What I am assuming is that, for some reason, preload was called again. I used to think that preload will be called only when a new w3wp.exe will be created (in turn meaning that app pool has recycled)

This behavior was observed  twice
Can anyone tell me anything about it

**EDIT**

Answer: Partial: its because of app-domain restart. I still do not know why app-domain got restarted

Comment: Try printing out the AppDomainID as well. ASP.NET can use multiple app domains per process (under circumstance that I don't fully understand).

Comment: @usr can you elaborate on it. What do you mean when you say "ASP.NET can use multiple app domains per process"

Comment: @usr there are two things: 1) ours is not an ASP.NET application, its a WCF application.

2) we have only one site. Which means only one App Domain. Hence, that scenario does not occur

Comment: When you redeploy for example you'll have two app domains for a short period of time. The old and the new version overlap in time.

Comment: @usr can you shed light on when all exactly does an app domain restart. I don't see any code making any changes to my /bin folder. And at many places I read that changes in App_Data folder also results in app domain restart. But when I tried to reproduce, it did not happen. Any changes in my App_Data folder did not lead to app-domain restart

Comment: I don't know. You will never be able to reliably prevent this from happening. Your code must live with it. You should not need to know the answer for this question. Note that app domains do not share static variables. Your problems cannot come from cross-appdomain interference through statics.

Comment: @usr when an App-Domain restart takes place, is my code running in w3wp.exe killed forcefully or will it give time for it to end gracefully? (as in all the destructors are called before terminating the application)