# IIS Preload feature is being fired twice

Tags: iis, preload

I'm facing an issue with `IIS` `IProcessHostPreloadClient`'s `Preload()` feature where the `Preload()` is being fired twice when:

- I recycle the app pool
- Also I noticed that when I stop the web site, `Preload()` is being called.

Comment: Could you include the code that defines Preload().  Its not going to be easy to help with such a broad question.

Comment: i'm in process of creating POC and just followed the instruction in the below link to make my application always running and to initialize during startup.

http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html

Comment: Just found similar issue but no solution yet.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27859599/erratic-behavior-of-preload#new-answer