# ASP.NET become very slow when add or remove dll in bin folder

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.NET site (.NET 4.0) with ~1200 dlls files
Every time I change dll in bin folder (add, remove or replace), my site became to very slow and need to wait about 10 minutes to connect again, sometime need to reset IIS

Is there any way to settings ASP.NET or IIS just load new dll, do not reload all dll?

Thank all!

Comment: You can try using a binary diff tool such as BeyondCompare and set it to perform binary comparison between two folders. You only need to deploy what has changed. I am still confused, is the copy taking the longest? If so You can easily generate a zip or rar file of files that have changed.

Comment: What the hell. 1200 DLLs? I think that's your problem! That's absurd.

Comment: Changes to bin force a recycle - http://stackoverflow.com/q/302110/314291

Answer (score 0):

> ASP.NET dynamic compilation enables you to modify your source code without having to explicitly compile your code before you deploy your Web application. If you modify a source file, ASP.NET automatically recompiles the file and updates all linked resources. By default, ASP.NET Web pages and code files are compiled dynamically when users first request a resource, such as an ASP.NET page (.aspx file), from a Web site. After pages and code files have been compiled the first time, the compiled resources are cached, so that subsequent requests to the same page are extremely efficient.
>   You can retrieve more information about ASP.NET dynamic compilation:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723(v=VS.100).aspx