# IIS, Updating Site, restart AppPool and Site?

Tags: asp.net, iis

Each time I make an update to one of my sites, I go into the IIS Manager and I first recycle the App Pool for that site, then restart the site itself.  Is this really required?

I restart the AppPool to make sure the new bins are compiled and running underneath the site (rather than waiting up to 20 minutes or so for it to do this automatically).

Then I restart the site itself, for good measure I suppose (to make sure all the views and such are properly re-evaluated by IIS).

Are both operations required?

- Will the AppPool automatically recycle if the site is restarted?
- Will the site automatically restart if the AppPool is recycled?

Comment: No, neither is required. If you update the site files it will be automatically handled. I've never had a situation where you would have to wait 20 minutes for the site to rebuild.

Comment: Any changes in the `/bin` folder will trigger a Recycle. So if you add/overwrite files there it will be done automatically as @SamiKuhmonen also writes.

Comment: @VDWWD just `/bin`, or other site folders as well?  I guess AppPool only need be concnered about the bin...  I suppose I'll have to do some deeper research on what restarting the site itself actually does.

Comment: There are other triggers, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302110/what-causes-an-application-pool-in-iis-to-recycle