# ASP.C# sporadically receives “This page can’t be found”

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, iis, windows-server-2008

Working in a small company and we have several ASP.C# applications all on 1 server (no load balancing).  One of the applications (ONLY MVC App in company), the users sporadically receives "This page can’t be found."  When I am notified, I attempt to pull up the same account and it magically works great, with no issues.  With that said, I am usually notified 30 minutes or more after the fact.  Due to the application pulling up fine for me, it seems not to be an application issue but either a network, server, or DB issue verses application.

The other ASP.C# applications on the save server seem to be working fine.  Some of them are use the same DB too.  I have been tasked to locate the issue.  *Are there any library’s or something that I can use on the server (for this 1 application) to log the time a request hits the server, time it take to process requests, db requests, etc?  Or **if you have any other suggestions***.  I am considering loading .log4net and just add major logging to before/after db calls, etc.  Just wondering if there is a better way.

*Using framework 4.6.1, MVC – v 5.2.3.0.  No Entity framework, using Store Procedures in Sybase ASE v15.0.3, Visual Studio 2015, Window’s Server 2008,  IIS 7, users on Windows 7 and IE 11.*

I do see on server logs, "A process serving application pool ‘%1’ failed to respond to a ping. The process id was ‘%2’.”  When an Event ID 5010.  Not 100% sure if these 2 are separate issues.

Comment: Have you already added `Elmah` or some other logging utility to try and capture any exception that may be occurring in the application? Also, have you reviewed the Event Viewer to see if any clues are in there? It sounds like something might be causing your app pool to recycle.

Comment: I have not looked into Elmah, but will.  Yes, I have looked into the Event viewer  "A process serving application pool ‘%1’ failed to respond to a ping. The process id was ‘%2’.” When an Event ID 5010. Not 100% sure if these 2 are separate issues.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, I provided issue, all the data around what is being used (versions), event viewer data from the server, and a suggested course of action (adding log4net and logging the user's each step).  The question is based on, if there are any better options.

Comment: If it is the app pool recycling, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302110/what-causes-an-application-pool-in-iis-to-recycle) for ideas on what might be causing it. As a last resort, you could proactively recycle the app at night to try and prevent it from happening during peak user hours.

Comment: That issue seems to indicate the App Pool is crashing. It will auto-restart itself, so users will only get errors during the period of downtime between when it crashes and when it comes back up. As to *why* it's crashing, that could be tricky to determine. Generally, that only happens because of something like a memory leak or page fault.

Comment: Yes, I will check into the App Pool restarting.  Also, Could this be due to Threads Per Processor Limit?  This particular app has major amount of async Task methods?  Also, could this be do to Memory Links with DB calls, not being properly shut down?