# Why an ASP.NET web site gets recompiled when renaming or deleting a folder inside

Tags: asp.net, web

I develop a simple file manager inside an ASP.NET Web site (not web application).

I notice that every time I rename or delete a **folder**, the site gets recompiled - i.e. the very next web request after delete or rename operation takes considerably much time to execute.

It's only true for folders, not for files. 
Why does this occur?

P.S. I use WebDev server (Cassini), haven't tested in on IIS yet.

UPDATE: The same disaster happens with ASP.NET MVC Web Applications :(

UPDATE 2: Here are similar discussions:

- [Storing temporary user files in ASP.NET in medium trust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271944/storing-temporary-user-files-in-aspnet-in-medium-trust)
- [ASP.NET restarts when a folder is created, renamed or deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248825/asp-net-restarts-when-a-folder-is-created-renamed-or-deleted)

Comment: Do they folders contain any files?

Comment: mxmissile: no, I experimented with only folders so far

Comment: Create a small project and deploy to IIS. Do you experience the same behavior?

Comment: Raj Kaimal: yes, the same. Can you reproduce it?

Answer (score 1):

Asp.net watches the folders and then runs compilation to keep up with any changes you make.  To overcome this you can use Non-updateable full precompilation, which you can read about [here](http://www.asp.net/%28S%28sf10gzjodvrpce55el2p5cnk%29%29/learn/hosting/tutorial-15-vb.aspx).

Comment: It is still recompiling on you or it doesn't allow you to create folders?  Also I just noticed you are using the dev server.  That is most likely part of the issue.  Maybe try it out on IIS and see if it is still recompiling.

Comment: BigJason: same on IIS, same on all types of web apps, you delete or rename forder and app gets recycled.

Answer (score 1):

You should move the files folder outside the project structure and probably use a virtual folder in IIS to keep the paths. This should not only prevent recompilation but will also make updating the code and backing up the user files easier because they will be separated.

Answer (score 0):

Where are the folders you are creating? Under App_Data?

Comment: No, ~/Storage. These files and folders must be available from web.